# Sending a string to client- receiving a TypeError

Tags: python

I'm trying to send an image to the client, so I have converted the image into a string. Here is my code:

```
def send_image_to_client(file_name, client_socket):
    """sends an image to the client"""

    with open(file_name, "rb") as im:
        string = base64.b64encode(im.read())  # convert image into a string
        print "sending image..."
        client_socket.send(string)

    return
```

For some reason, I get the following error:

> send() argument 1 must be string or buffer, not None

What am I doing wrong?

This example shows the same error:

```
def show_content(directory, client_socket):
"""displays the content of a given directory"""
import glob
files_list = glob.glob(directory+"\*.*")
files_list[-1] += "--"
for address in files_list:
    if address:
        send_response_to_client(address+"*", client_socket)
return
```

Comment: make sure the file exists and it actually has content. put `print(im.read())` and `print(string)` to get to know which one is empty.

Comment: The problem is not the content, but what I send to the client. When I print string, I get a string.

Comment: Is it a system bug?

Answer (score 0):

The above code is really the code that you are trying or you have done any cleanup before posting it here?
You can try this -

```
with open(file_name, "rb") as im:
    string = base64.b64encode(im.read())  # convert image into a string
    print "sending image..."
    print(type(string))
    if (string):
        client_socket.send(string.encode())
    else:
        print("No Data received from base64encode")
return
```

Comment: Any other string doesn't work either, not only this one.

Comment: Try using the encode() method which gives us bytes. What was the output of the type(string) and did you get "No Data received ..." message? Can you tell us more about the socket that you are using?

Comment: When I print it I get letters... so I guess it's a string

Comment: Did you try executing the code that I wrote above? What was the output, can you paste that here? The client_socket object is a python socket class obtained from a server socket.accept() or is it a client socket?

Comment: I have found the problem it was a stupid mistake in another part of the code. Thank you very much!!